# D (Tango) can read and write ANSI files?

Tags: file, encoding, d, ansi, tango

With D and Tango library can I read and write in the ANSI encoding ?

Comment: Yes, file input/output is encoding agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tango has a few simple functions for [converting between ANSI and ASCI](http://dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/stable/tango.sys.win32.CodePage.html). Reading and writing via [tango.io.device.File](http://dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/stable/tango.io.device.File.html) should preserve the data just fine.